# YAF - Authenticate user from main page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, yaf

**Specs:**

- MVC 4 RAZOR
- C#
- IIS
- 7.5
- Using YAF - http://yetanotherforum.net/
- .NET 4

**What's happening?**

I have a site: http://www.mysite.com and at that site I have set up YAF and when a user visits http://www.mysite.com/forum they are taken to the forum.

**What do I want?**

When a user logs into my site, I want to create a cookie for them so that when the user visits http://www.mysite.com/forum they are automatically logged into the forum.

**What have I done?**

When the user registers on my site a YAF account is created for them (working fine).
When the user logs into my site, I authenticate them and create a cookie but I also want to create a cookie for the forum so that the user does not have to log into the forum separately.

To create the cookie for the user I am doing this (so that YAF detects them as logged in):

```
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, "");
    var encryptedTicket = CookieHelper.EncryptTicket(ticket);
    var cookie = CookieHelper.CreateCookie(encryptedTicket, ".YAFNET_Authentication");
    cookie.Path = "/";
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    CookieHelper.AddCookie(cookie);
```

I am expecting to now be authenticated when I visit http://www.mysite.com/forum

Anybody have any words of wisdom?

--Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind...

Here is the solution:

> Added a  section to both web.config's with the same
>   values. This allows the main website to create an encrypted session
>   key for the login that the YAF site can decrypt. Put this within the
>    section. Change the keys to a random 48-hex-character
>   value of your own (I used RoboForm to generate my keys).

```
<machineKey validationKey="DBAEF98E532D4161826F8351C794DFD27C0F814262FD6986"
decryptionKey="DBAEF98E532D4161826F8351C794DFD27C0F814262FD6986"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Answer found here: [Log in YAF user](http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/yaf_postst8780_Custom-membership-and-role-provider-with-YAF-Profile-provider.aspx#post35642)

Hope it helps someone else one day.